# How to prevent users (authors) to add new tags in single post?

Tags: wordpress

How i can restrict authors from adding new tags when publishing new post?
I need force theme to using only current tags.

Best Regards

Comment: What user levels do you have?

Comment: @ David Angulo : for authors (not editors). thx